What file should go into the option "Raster Mask Layer"

Good day,
I am currently doing a project in which I converted a .map file, used the function in PCRaster Tools "Covert PCRaster maps to column file" in which it exported it as a .csv file. I then took the file into python, cleaned it up a bit and tried using the function, "Column file to PCRaster maps" This window then popped up. All I understand except the "Raster mask layer" What file should I put there in order to make it work?
